# When should a direct object pronoun be ommitted?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, compléments, ellipse

I have recently begun to notice a number of places where the direct object is ommitted in translating from English to French.

For instance, I saw *I'll find it* translated as *Je vais trouver,* rather than *Je vais le trouver.* And I've been told to translate "I knew that!" as *Je le savais!* but “I didn't know that” as *Je ne savais pas*! There are many other examples.

I'm trying to determine whether there is any sort of intuitive rule for this, whether it completely depends on the verb, or whether it depends completely on the context.

Another one I often see is "J'aime," and almost never "Je l'aime," in response to being asked whether if they like something.

Is there any way to predict whether I should use the direct object or not?

Comment: Off hand, I'd say both (verb & context). About your 1st  example, I'd use *je vais trouver* if talking about an idea, and *je vais le trouver* if talking about an object. Concerning your second example I'd never use *je savais* to say "I knew it/that", I'd spontaneously  say *Je le savais* (sounding as  *jel' savais* in colloquial speech); but I'm pretty sure *je savais* could be used.

Comment: Blame Gilles, he told me *je savais* was more idiomatic. All his fault.

Comment: @Aerovistae No I didn't! Did you mean [this](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/1098?m=11274478#11274478)? « Je ne savais pas » is idiomatic, but « je savais » isn't. Yes, it's weird.

Comment: Ha. Yes. Go figure.

Answer (score 4):

In the first case, you don't know what you'll find (it's not concrete, you don't know the answer as you're still searching).
*I'll find it* → *Je vais trouver* or *Je vais trouver la réponse* (*la réponse* is a concrete element here)

In the two other cases, you've been told something, it's not abstract anymore. You can use the pronoun to refer to that thing (but it's not mandatory)
*I knew that* → *Je savais* or *Je le savais*
*I didn't know that* → *Je ne savais pas* or *Je ne le savais pas*

Edit: you could translate *I'll find it* as *Je vais trouver ça*, *ça* being the shortened form of *cela*. *Cela* refers to abstract subjects whereas the subject of *le* should be determined.

Comment: Users like Quentin here always confuse me. You created a Stack Exchange account, answered this one question, then never came back. Why?? If you ever do come back, I'm really just curious.

Comment: Please tag me in your response to @Aerovistae, I'm also intrigued. No presence on any other site, no questions...very curious. Gamified Q&A - what could be better?

Comment: @cccg03 Have you really searched the web to find me? I'm flattered :)

Comment: @Aerovistae Je passe beaucoup de temps sur les multiples sites du StackExchange Network, surtout pour les réponses qui y sont apportées. De temps en temps j'essaie aussi de répondre à quelques questions, mais il y a beaucoup de personnes plus compétentes et plus rapides que moi. Je n'ai pas non plus envie de dédier ma vie à patrouiller sur ce site.
Est-ce que ça rend ma réponse plus fausse ou moins intéressante ? J'en doute.

Answer (score 2):

C'est un phénomène d'ellipse.

- Si l'objet que remplace le pronom est évident, il peut souvent être omis. Cela dépend aussi de la fonction de l'objet. C'est très fréquent avec un COD, moins avec un COI (car souvent obligatoire grammaticalement).

Je le vois => Je vois : BON

Je lui parle => Je parle : MAUVAIS

Il est intéressant de savoir qu'au moyen-âge le pronom sujet faisait ordinairement défaut, parce que les terminaisons verbales, étant encore sonores, indiquaient suffisamment les personnes grammaticales: *Ma chiere amie, que avez ? Feras ?* (Grevisse 14, 667).

- Il y a aussi des cas où des pronoms s'effacent de manière formelle (cf Grevisse 14,659):

  - le, la les s'effacent devant lui: Je (le) lui jurai solennellement, il (le) lui demanda, ...
  - y se supprime devant le futur et conditionnel d'aller, ainsi qu'après lui: tu (y) iras, quand il (y) irait de toute sa fortune ...
  - en se supprime devant lui-même: il remplit un verre de vin => il (en) en remplit un
- *A contrario*, il existe différents cas de redondance, avec *y* et *en* notamment: c'en est fait de ... admis par l'Académie en 1932. S'y connaître en depuis 1988, en avoir assez de ...

Comment: "Ma chiere amie, que avez ? Feras ?" .... what. I gather "chiere" is old French for "cher"...but...."que avez"...where's the contraction!!

Comment: Ma chère amie, qu'avez-vous ? Feras-tu ? - Eh non ! pas de contraction non plus.